# How do I extend a default docker image command without interrupting the default behaviour

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm using the following docker-compose settings:

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.5
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
    MYSQL_USER: userx
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
```

and I need to be able to update the permissions of the user with the command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'userx' with grant option;
```

But I don't want to change the default command so I can continue to use the settings as above. But I really don't know what the best approach is.

I tried to create my own image from the above:

```
FROM mysql:5.5
CMD mysqld && mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'snap' with grant option;"
```

can anyone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions.

1. Custom image

   ```
   FROM mysql:5.5
   RUN mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'snap' with grant option;"
   ```

Edit: This option is not tested.

2. Mount (i.e. add volume) an `.sql` file with the GRANT command, or an `.sh` file with the `mysql -u ...` command to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder on the container.

Edit: the working `sh` file content, as tested by @jonnie is

```
mysql --user="root" --password="rootpass" -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'snap' with grant option;"
```

Comment: I tried option 1 and i get the error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)` I tried using . this prevents it building the image so I did some googling and from that found if I put `exit 0` after it it builds but I still get that error

Comment: option 2 worked but I had to change command to `mysql --user="root" --password="rootpass" -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'snap' with grant option;"` using the `-p` and `-u` flags didn't seem to work

Comment: Thanks! I've added my answer to include the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the Docker Hub [page for that image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/):

> Environment Variables
>
> When you start the mysql image, you can adjust the configuration of
>   the MySQL instance by passing one or more environment variables on the
>   docker run command line. Do note that none of the variables below will
>   have any effect if you start the container with a data directory that
>   already contains a database: any pre-existing database will always be
>   left untouched on container startup.

So if you don't have a data directory, then you can set some environment variables and the image will perform the `GRANT`s for you. It would appear that the current `docker-compose` configuration is correct for this behaviour.

> MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD This variable is mandatory and specifies the
>   password that will be set for the MySQL root superuser account. In the
>   above example, it was set to my-secret-pw.
>
> MYSQL_DATABASE This variable is optional and allows you to specify the
>   name of a database to be created on image startup. If a user/password
>   was supplied (see below) then that user will be granted superuser
>   access (corresponding to GRANT ALL) to this database.
>
> MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD These variables are optional, used in
>   conjunction to create a new user and to set that user's password. This
>   user will be granted superuser permissions (see above) for the
>   database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable. Both variables are
>   required for a user to be created.
>
> Do note that there is no need to use this mechanism to create the root
>   superuser, that user gets created by default with the password
>   specified by the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable.